# Is EAX crypto mode supported in the .NET framework?

Tags: .net, cryptography

Does anyone know if EAX mode is supported or how to use it?  Here is an overview:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that it is.

And to make matters worse, the two building blocks of EAX - counter mode encryption and the CMAC authentication code - also do not seem to be supported by the standard .NET crypto libraries. At least, CTR mode isn't included in the [CipherMode enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ciphermode.aspx), and the only subclasses of `KeyedHashAlgorithm` (.NET's name for MACs) are HMAC and a TripleDES-based MAC (probably an old CBC-MAC, which is close-ish to CMAC but not quite). So it seems you couldn't even easily cobble together an EAX using existing components; you'd seemingly have to implement everything from scratch.

It may be better to just use another mode (like CBC) in combination with an HMAC for message authentication.

Comment: Technically this answer is correct (I specified the framework) so I accepted it.  For anyone needing to do EAX though, I'd go with BouncyCastle as Greg suggested.

Answer (score 4):

The bouncycastle C# crypto library supports GCM and possibly other AEAD ciphers.