# .NET support for authentication-encryption algorithms?

Tags: cryptography

First off, I'm not talking about the traditional symmetric or asymmetric encryption - I'm referring to authentication-encryption (AE) algorithms or modes like [EAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode) or GCM/[Galois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode) (which use symmetric crypto within). I also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046535/is-eax-crypto-mode-supported-in-the-net-framework) but that's over 2.5 years old!

So the question: Has Microsoft released authentication-encryption classes as part of the official .NET framework? I swear I searched and found nothing. So I'm wondering if they are called under a different label or something?

Side note: The best AE mode, OCB, had [it's license relaxed](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/ocb/license.htm) just 2 weeks back :) Goody!

Comment: Thanks for that heads up on OCB, Sid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [bouncy castle c# to do GCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net/10366194#10366194) pretty easily, however microsoft released a separate framework [CLR Security](http://clrsecurity.codeplex.com/) that added gcm support, but it hasn't seen any movement in 3 years.